# Sound Design Reel 

Tags: demo, reel, feedback

Hi guys,

This is my first demo reel( http://vimeo.com/33159167 ) and wanted to share with you. Any comments are welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 1):

great attention to detail, great variety of clips, good pacing, the only thing is maybe the door creek at the beginning is a little too in your face, if you were thinking of adding any other clips to this vid i would recommend something sci-fi because this is mainly a 'foley' show-reel, it would give you a chance to demonstrate use of synthesis, good stuff marco, cal

Answer (score 0):

hy. not bad, but it should be clarified. i agree with grand sound, for example the last was too dry. i hear, u wanted to be accurate in rythm, but spend at least as much attention to howe its sounds like. try to be better positioned in the space.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I left it dry cause I wasn't the rerecording mixer. So, I wanted to be as faithfull as possible of my creative input. 

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was great, the main two slightly critical points I had were the two already mentioned with the loud door creak in the first and the last one a bit dead, but you explained all that. Maybe the camera taking is a bit loud but then the character does react to it so I can see why that is. Oh and maybe the gunshots in Absent were slightly weedy sounding, possibly a bit more realistic but not what you'd normally get in a hollywood film for example.

But yeah really really good job, well done.
Dominic